# Highlighting measures in LilyPond

Tags: lilypond

In LilyPond, is there a way to highlight one or several bars with a colored box? Similar to this: https://musescore.org/en/node/220071

If it is not possible, it could be done once it has been converted to pdf, with some pdf tuning package. In that case, I would need the start/end "coordinates" of the bar to highlight. Is it possible to obtain this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With version v2.23, there *is* a way to highlight passages.

This can be done with the `\staffHighlight` command, which takes a colour as an argument.

See: [1.7.1 Inside the staff - Staff highlights](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/notation/inside-the-staff#staff-highlights)

Comment: Thank you! For my particular application, it is possible that the same passage may need to be highlighted with two colors. I would like to get the intersection region to have both colors overlapping (with some opacity). Something like: https://drive.upm.es/s/QFc58j7vbx7hjiu I think this is not achievable by setting the parameter ```\staffHighlightsetting```. Isn't it?

Comment: @Kikolo  
Not exactly, because each new `\staffHighlight` implicitly writes `\stopStaffHighlight`.  But, you could easily fake it by choosing an in-between colour for the overlapping region.

Comment: Thank you, I thought so. However, for my project I would find it much easier to simply set some rectangles in the pdf once it is generated. I will create a new question for this