# Page coordinates of a measure in LilyPond

Tags: lilypond

*(related to [this](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/125799/highlighting-measures-in-lilypond/125800?noredirect=1#comment232186_125800) question)*

In LilyPond, is there any way to know the "coordinates" (i.e. position relative to the top left corner of the page) that a given measure (start/end) will have in the resulting pdf?

Comment: Didn't @elements-in-space's comment about using an in-between color for the overlapping region solve your problem?

Comment: If possible, I would find it much easier to simply set some rectangles in the pdf once generated, instead of struggling with the "intersection region" between fragments, and color mixing. So I would prefer this approach if possible.